# error message with update query in mysq, php

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, sql-update

I am using this syntax to update message:

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
$ans=mysql_query("UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3', WHERE username =$uname") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

`$uname` is `userxyz` here and error  message is:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username =userxyx' at line 1

Same error if I put  in single quotes like `'$uname'` or even if I use `'".$_POST['username']."'` in update query.

Comment: Try removing the comma here `pass3='$t3', WHERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the comma (,) before where, and you should put $uname in \"$uname\"

```
$ans=mysql_query("UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3' WHERE username =\"$uname\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
$ans=mysql_query("UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3' WHERE username =$uname") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

Try to remove "**,**" (comma) before the `where` condition in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove comma (,) before where

```
"UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3' WHERE username =$uname"
```

2. You should change your 
   `$tags` to `addslashes($tags)`

before updating through raw query. Learn [here](http://php.net/addslashes)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query

```
"UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3', WHERE username =$uname"
```

to

```
"UPDATE userdata SET tag1 = '$tag1', tag2 = '$tag2', tag3 = '$tag3', pass1='$t1', pass2='$t2', pass3='$t3' WHERE username =$uname"
```

You need to run your query in phpmyadmin or mysql cli first and then try it in code. So you will directly know where is problem.

Comment: it would be helpful to advise what aspect of the query is changing, and even better to say why.